# stargazer() captions in multiple tables

Tags: r, stargazer

I have a data set with some variables to summarize and a group membership indicator

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100), 
                 var2 = rnorm(100), 
                 group = rep(c("A","B"), each = 50))
```

where I want to generate summary tables for groups `A` and `B` separately. We can do this using `dplyr` and `purrr` as follows:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% split(. $group) %>% walk(~ stargazer(., type = "text", title = unique(df$group)))


A
==========================================================
Statistic N  Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
----------------------------------------------------------
var1      50 0.371  1.044   -2.350  -0.251   1.043   2.545
var2      50 0.014  0.849   -2.212  -0.407   0.584   1.710
----------------------------------------------------------

A
===========================================================
Statistic N   Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
-----------------------------------------------------------
var1      50 0.016   1.246   -2.432  -1.107   0.879   2.551
var2      50 -0.031  0.975   -2.713  -0.682   0.465   2.022
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

where I naively tried to introduce the group names as table captions by handing over `unique(df$group)` to the `title` parameter of `stargazer()`. When we do this, only the first element of the provided vector of table captions is used and all tables therefore have caption `A`. Is there a solution that results in the correct table captions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply changing your existing code as follows:

`df %>% split(. $group) %>% walk(~ stargazer(., type = "text", title = .$group))`

Replace `unique(df$group)` by `.$group` and it will work. Don't forget to add the library call for `stargazer`. The reason is that by using `unique(df$group)` you pass a character veector of length two to stargazer and by definition it only takes the first argument. By using `.$group` it depends on the respective group and you obtain the right title.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stargazer)

df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100), 
                 var2 = rnorm(100), 
                 group = rep(c("A","B"), each = 50))

df %>% split(. $group) %>% walk(~ stargazer(., type = "text", title = .$group))
    
A
===========================================================
Statistic N   Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
-----------------------------------------------------------
var1      50 -0.122  1.019   -3.582  -0.671   0.511   2.223
var2      50 0.082   1.077   -2.780  -0.702   0.841   2.203
-----------------------------------------------------------

B
===========================================================
Statistic N   Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
-----------------------------------------------------------
var1      50 0.023   0.971   -2.431  -0.706   0.609   2.299
var2      50 -0.041  1.039   -3.807  -0.626   0.718   1.950
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iwalk` which will pass data as well as name of the list.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)

df %>% 
  split(. $group) %>% 
  iwalk(~stargazer(.x, type = "text", title = .y))

A
===========================================================
Statistic N   Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
-----------------------------------------------------------
var1      50 -0.064  0.890   -2.265  -0.744   0.734   1.699
var2      50 -0.130  1.003   -2.404  -0.752   0.581   1.930
-----------------------------------------------------------

B
==========================================================
Statistic N  Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
----------------------------------------------------------
var1      50 0.086  0.823   -1.737  -0.476   0.742   1.736
var2      50 0.167  1.178   -1.709  -0.670   0.898   2.677
----------------------------------------------------------
```